# Setting ActionMenuView font family/typeface

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, fonts

I am currently working on an application on Xamarin & I am trying to set the ActionMenuView's font family (on the navigation bar), but I have found nothing to set the font family on this object.

Moreover, I wanted to set the title's font family & I made a custom renderer that is working perfectly. So I tried the same for the ActionMenuView but it does not have any typeface/font-family attribute on it.

My custom renderer (working) :

```
    private void Toolbar_ChildViewAdded(object sender, ChildViewAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        // here I can pass on the ActionMenuView object but it does not have any typeface property?
        if (e.Child.GetType() == typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView))
        {
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView AppCompatTextView = ((Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView)e.Child);
            AppCompatTextView.SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, "MontserratRegular.otf"), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            _toolbar.ChildViewAdded -= Toolbar_ChildViewAdded;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about "ActionMenuView"? Is it a XAML content page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create  style:

```
<style name="Style_font">
<item name="fontFamily">@fonts/PTSerif-Bold.ttf</item>
</style>
```

Then use this style in Menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

In MainActivity.cs:

```
 Android.Support.V7.Widget.ActionMenuView bottombar =FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.ActionMenuView>(Resource.Id.toolbar_bottom);
        IMenu bottomMenu = bottombar.Menu;
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Drawable.menu_bottom_view_pager,bottomMenu);
```

I don't test, but you can try